# What does ";" in "If in Your Dreams; the Flood" mean?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Context: "If in Your Dreams; the Flood" is the title of a visual novel. In short, it's story about a girl who suffers from constant nightmares, namely she has dreasm about the flood, and each time she sleeps the flood becomes more dangerous and frightening.

I suspect that ";" meant to show that the visual novel has TWO names, ("If in Your Dreams" and "The Flood" respectively), they were just combined in one title.

Am I correct? If not, then what can it mean?

Comment: Crosspost of https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/180206/4376

Comment: @Chenmunka Is it bad to crosspost?

Comment: It is frowned upon to post identical questions on multiple sites, even if on-topic on each site.  You may get one of them deleted.

Comment: It's literature. Get the author's mind from reading the work. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris I just expected that there may be some rule about using semicolon for similiar cases. Or maybe that there are other examples that can shed light on the title.

Comment: There indeed are rules for semicolon usage. We indeed can find similar constructions in literature. See also [writers.se] Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris Do you suggest to crosspost this question to Writing?

Comment: No, do not. If it is found to be better suited for Writing, it will be closed here and migrated there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This boils down to reference styles. I wouldn't go so far as to say that it's wrong, but there's definitely some nonstandard usage here.

A more common style would be to write the two titles as follows:

> If in Your Dreams; or, The Flood

Reference reading: See "Double Titles" at https://style.mla.org/punctuation-with-titles/

Or "The Flood" could be the subtitle. In which case, it would be rendered as follows in most styles:

> If in Your Dreams: The Flood

Reference reading: See "Titles and Subtitles" at https://style.mla.org/punctuation-with-titles/

I am sorry that I can't really answer your question.

Comment: >subtitle What is "subtitle"? I have never heard about such thing.

Comment: Let's just say it is a secondary title. For example, in "Alternative splicing: New insights from global analyses," "Alternative splicing" is the main title and the part after the colon is the subtitle.

Answer (score -1):

This is the title of a non-fiction work. Like the text itself, the title is the work of the imagination of the writer. In fiction, writers do not have to follow widely-held practices, including practices in punctuation and grammar. We have no way of knowing *why* the writer titled the "book" (it is actually the name of one of three stories that occur in [a computer game](https://watercress.itch.io/cautionary-tale)) *If in Your Dreams; the Flood*. It is part of a work of art.  It is fiction; fiction doesn't have to use standard grammar. Ask the writer why they chose that wording/punctuation in that title.

Comment: Poetic license is respected, and I agree with what Knotell says here about fiction not always following widely held practices. However, I do feel that good fiction does not unnecessarily violate most of the standard grammar rules.

In this particular case, I am not quite sure the writer named it so. This was probably written in a listing of the writer's works. A nonstandard listing causes confusion (as we have seen here).
If this is the name of the actual work, I apologise for dissecting it. :)